# php header redirection to a new page instead of below current page

Tags: php, redirect, header

Hye developers, I'm designing a payment gateway that will authenticate user card details, I want redirect user to a page if its correct and payment is successful, I'm using

```
  <?php

require_once 'wallet.class.php';
$class = new wallet('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pooldb', "root", ""); // change the host and database to the host server




// making payment 
if(isset($_REQUEST["amount"])){

$card = [
  "card_no" => $_REQUEST["cardNO"],
  "cvv" => $_REQUEST["cvc"],
  "expiry_month" => $_REQUEST["month"],
  "expiry_year" => $_REQUEST["year"]
];

$info = [
    "id" => 1, // Login in user
    "amount" => $_REQUEST["amount"], // amount
    "url" => "http://payment.php" // response URL
];

$token = $class->Tokenize($_REQUEST["auth"], $card, $_REQUEST["bvn"]);

if($token == "Token True"){
    $payment = $class->Payment($card, $info);

    if($payment == "Paid True"){
        $class->CheckUser_AndSave($info["id"], $info["amount"]);

        header("Location:upload.php");
        exit();
    }
    else if($payment == "Paid False"){
        // make an action to dispaly and input box and button for OTP 
        echo "Paid False";
        $_SESSION['mssage'] = $class->message;
    }
    else{
        echo $payment; // error message
    }
}
else{
    echo "Your card was not tokenize. Try agin.";
}
}

 // doing OTP action here
elseif (isset ($_REQUEST["otp"])) { // Send entered OTP here
$info = [
    "id" => 1, // Login in user
    "amount" => $_REQUEST["amount"], // amount
];

$otp = $class->OTP($_REQUEST["otp"]);

if($otp == "OTP True"){
    $class->CheckUser_AndSave($info["id"], $info["amount"]);
}
else{
    echo "Something went wrong.";
}
}
```

but instead of redirecting to upload page, it only display it below the current page and everything is stretch, please I need help

Comment: one way would be to add javascript code inside your php condition `window.location = 'http://website.com/upload.php'`

Comment: do I need to echo <script> tag it like html element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: @AbdullahiYusuf yes just like one of the answers below

Answer (score 0):

You should probably redirect and exit like the following,

```
if($payment == "Paid True"){
    $class->CheckUser_AndSave($info["id"], $info["amount"]);
    header("Location:upload.php");
    exit();
}
```

Also make sure you haven't echoed/printed anything before this line.

Comment: Yes I havn't echo anything, but it still displayed below

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Without that its quite difficult to debug?

Comment: Try displaying errors and warnings and find whether there is any.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to redirect as Japanguy suggest, it now works

```
if($payment == "Paid True"){
        $class->CheckUser_AndSave($info["id"], $info["amount"]);

        echo "<script>
            window.location.href='upload.php';
        </script>";
    }
```